# How to make RecyclerView inflate all items at once?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I was using a `ScrollView` for displaying some (5-7) heterogeneous information card (Each of them has its different layout and can contain sub RecyclerViews and images which is complex). However for tablet support I'd like to use `RecyclerView`'s existing `LayoutManager`s for linear/grid layout switching.

When I was using `ScrollView`, all views are inflated at once, and the lag only comes at loading which is unnoticeable. However when switched to a `RecyclerView`, the views are inflated upon scrolling and the scroll lags noticeably.

So how can I force `RecyclerView` to inflate all items at once, and do not recycle them, just like a `ScrollView`? I've taken a glance at `Recycler`s and `LayoutManager`s but couldn't get a clue. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: where is your adapter code in your question???

Comment: I think you deeply misunderstand the point of view recycling. In any case the problem is that whatever you are doing when binding the data to your views is taking way to long. The `RecyclerView` is doing exactly what it is supposed to. Show us  the code in your `Adapter` and we can help you fix the actual problem.

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your question correct, but what about `yourRecyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(size)` ? From the docs: `...allowing a LayoutManager to reuse those views unmodified...` . Isn´t that what you need? And in generell: Xaver is right, I think You misunderstood the recyclerView..

Comment: The entire point of a Recycler view is to not inflate items before needed.  If you're seeing noticable lag, then you aren't implementing your adapter correctly.

Comment: @XaverKapeller Yes I know the problem is the item-inflating and binding time, however it needs to be complex as that because of the app's content (binding 4-6 views and a nested horizontal RecyclerView with 10 image items and text above the image) and each item is heterogeneous. If the user scrolls quickly and triggers two items of this type to be inflated when scrolling I don't believe it can work without any lag.

Comment: (Continues...) So since the work is constant, I'd prefer doing it initially instead of when scrolling. As for the adapter code it is super-simple, just inflating and binding to different layouts depending on position.

Comment: It can without a doubt work without any lag at all. In fact that is the whole point of view recycling - to reuse existing views over and over again and therefor vastly increase the performance and efficiency. The problem here is not view recycling. It's your code. Doesn't matter how complex your layout is. All views that are required to fill the screen are inflated in the beginning - just like you want them to. After that any performance issue is your fault. Most likely because you are doing stuff on the UI thread which you either can move to a background thread or can do more efficiently.

Comment: Nevertheless without seeing your code nobody can give you any real advice. We can just speculate. Please show us your code and we can help you fix this.

Comment: @XaverKapeller Thanks for your patience, here is the code https://github.com/DreaminginCodeZH/Douya/blob/master/app/src/main/java/me/zhanghai/android/douya/profile/ui/ProfileAdapter.java

Comment: But I think the problem is that I cannot do view recycling here because all the complex items can be completely heterogeneous - so I was asking for a workaround here.

Comment: To the downvoter: I'm asking a real question with efforts to give the clearest description. If you read carefully through the question and comments you'll know I'm facing a situation where such a workaround is necessary. If you really want to downvote or close this question please at least give some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

It’s clear that you haven’t figured out the reason for the lag. If it’s because the layout size changes abruptly, you need to handle the layout height when it’s not loaded. If it really lags when loading, then you should solve the problem of lag instead of loading all at once, because loading all at once will be even more laggy. If you really don’t want to solve the problem at all or the amount of data is really small, you can write it like this: add a ‘NestedScrollView’ as the parent of ‘RecyclerView’, and the height of ‘RecyclerView’ is ‘wrap_content’ and add ‘android:nestedScrollingEnabled=“false”’ to indicate that it should be filled without scrolling.

Answer (score -2):

try to add `android:fillViewport="true"` for your `ScrollView` in the xml file.